# Perl module Net::ARP, arp_lookup

Tags: perl, module, cpan, arp

I want to look up a MAC adrress by an IP.

```
use Net::ARP;
$mac = Net::ARP::arp_lookup($dev,"192.168.1.1");
```

But on the CPAN page, they don't explain what is this `$dev` variable for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dev is the network interface to use to try to connect to the given IP address.  In the other methods, 'lo' and 'eth0' are given as examples.

Comment: Ok, i changed $dev to "eth0" (this is my interface) but when running i got the error : `SIOCGARP: No device or address`

Comment: @eouti : Does running the script via sudo help?

Comment: FWIW, I was able to successfully get my router's mac address, but not that of any other device connected to the router, even though I can connect to them.